# Membership site with PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, membership

I have a html site, and I have a page that acts as a bio for users (which I currently have to update by hand with html).

I want to create a membership login page, and I want users to be able to input their own data, that in turn updates their bio page automatically. With an option to upload images.

I read up and looks like php and mysql is the way to go, which I know nothing about. Is that the right route? Or is there an easier way?

Kick me in the right direction to get that setup please? I'm lazy and don't want to spend months figuring out how everything works just to setup one page...

Comment: This is not a code writing service. You'll get better answers if you start writing your own code and come back to ask about specific problems you may run into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not try to write everything your own.

If you only want the result fast, find some mature CMS to start from. Try [Drupal](http://drupal.org) or [Wordpress](http://wordpress.org).

If you want more control and not afraid to fight with code, try framework like [Laravel](https://laravel.com/) or [Symfony](http://symfony.com). Learn as much APIs as possible from the framework.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into Wordpress. They offer hundreds of thousands of [plugins](https://wordpress.org/plugins/) that can achieve advanced functionality without writing any code.

Here is a Wordpress plugin called [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/) that looks like it would achieve your desired functionality.